# Error while compiling list of symbols when using Greek letters

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, lists

I am writing a list of symbols and acronyms for my thesis using `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}` and `\usepackage{multicol}` I have no issues for Latin letters, but when I want to use, for example, the definition for   `\acro{$\lambda$} {Wavelength}\acused{$\lambda$}`. I got an error. I have no clue about the cause of this error. If someone has a suggestion to avoid this error, I am more than grateful. My code for the list of symbols is below. I would like to conserve the format with two columns.

```
\chapter{List of symbols and acronyms}
        The next list describes several abbreviations that will be later used within the body of the document.  

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \begin{acronym}[VBLAST]  % longest acronym to fix width

        
        
    
        
        \acro{$I_{G}$}
        {Current-generation}\acused{$I_{G}$}
        
        
        \acro{$I_{R}$}
        {Current-recombination}\acused{$I_{R}$}
        
        \acro{$I_{GR}$}
        {Total device current}\acused{$I_{GR}$}
        
        \acro{$I_{D}$}
        {Radiant intensity}\acused{$I_{D}$}
        
        \acro{$I_e$}
        {Diffusion current}\acused{$I_e$}
        
        
        \acro{$E_e$}
        {Radiant flux}\acused{$E_e$}
        
        \acro{$I_e$}
        {Radiant intensity}\acused{$I_e$}
        
        \acro{$L_e$}
        {Radiance}\acused{$L_e$}
        
        \acro{$r$}
        {Radiation}\acused{$r$}
        
        \acro{$L_e$}
        {Radiance}\acused{$L_e$}
        
        \acro{$N_{el}$}
        {Number of injected electrons}\acused{$N_{el}$}
        
        \acro{$I$}
        {Current}\acused{$I$}
        
        \acro{$Q$}
        {Quantity of charge contained in a current running for a specified time}\acused{$Q$}
        
        \acro{$t$}
        {Time}\acused{$t$}
        
        \acro{$q$}
        {Elementary charge}\acused{$q$}
        
        \acro{$\lambda$}
        {Wavelength}\acused{$\lambda$}
                    

        \acro{LED}
            {Light emitting diode}\acused{LED}
            
        \acro{GaAs}
            {Gallium arsenide}\acused{GaAs}

        \acro{OLEDs}
            {Organic LEDs}\acused{OLEDs}

        \acro{QLEDs}
        {Quantum dot LEDs}\acused{QLEDs}

        \acro{ITO}
        {Indium tin oxide}\acused{ITO}

        \acro{SiNC}
        {Silicon nanocrystal}\acused{SiNC}

        \acro{QD}
        {Quantum dot}\acused{QD}
        
        \acro{QC}
        {Quantum confinement}\acused{QC}
        
        
        \acro{CB}
        {Conduction band}\acused{CB}
        
        \acro{VB}
        {Valence band}\acused{VB}
        
        \acro{Si}
        {Silicon}\acused{Si}
        
        \acro{Ge}
        {Germanium}\acused{Ge}
        
        \acro{I-V}
        {Current-voltage}\acused{I-V}
        

        
        \acro{ETL}
        {Electron transport layer}\acused{ETL}
        
        \acro{HTL}
        {Hole transport layer}\acused{HTL}
        

        
        \acro{DOS}
        {Density of states}\acused{DOS}
        
        
        \acro{HOMO}
        {Highest occupied molecular orbital}\acused{HOMO}
        
        \acro{LUMO}
        {Lowest unoccupied molecular orbital}\acused{LUMO}
        
        \acro{HF}
        {Hydrofluoric acid}\acused{HF}
        
        \acro{HSQ}
        {Hydrogen silsesquioxane}\acused{HSQ}
        
        \acro{H}
        {Hydrogen}\acused{H}
        
        \acro{NC}
        {Nanocrystal}\acused{NC}
        
        
        \acro{TCE}
        {Transparent conductive electrode}\acused{TCE}
        
        \acro{HWF}
        {High work function}\acused{HWF}
        
        \acro{LWF}
        {Low work function}\acused{LWF}
        
        \acro{TCM}
        {Transparent conductive materials}\acused{TCM}
        
        \acro{PEDOT:PSS}
        {Poly[3{,}4-ethylenedioxythiophene]
            :poly[styrenesulfonate]}\acused{PEDOT:PSS}
        
        
        \acro{Poly-TPD}
        {Poly[N{,}N’-bis-4-butylphenyl-N{,}N’-bisphenyl]benzidine}\acused{Poly-TPD}
        
        \acro{MEH-PPP}
        {=Poly[2-methoxy-5-(2-ethylhexyloxy)-1{,}4-phenylene]}\acused{MEH-PPP}
        
        \acro{PVK}
        {Poly[9-vinylcarbazole]}\acused{PVK}
        
        \acro{MEH-PPV}
        {Poly[2-methoxy-5-(2-ethylhexyloxy)-1{,}4-phenylenevinylene]}\acused{MEH-PPV}
        
        \acro{ZnO}
        {Zinc oxide}\acused{ZnO}
        
        \acro{TPBi}
        {2{,}2'{,}2''-(1{,}3{,}5-Benzinetriyl)-tris(1-phenyl-1-H-benzimidazole)}\acused{TPBi}
        
        %\acro{Mo\ch{O_{3}}}
        %{Molybdenum trioxide}\acused{Mo\ch{O_{3}}}
        
        
        \acro{PMMA}
        {Polymethyl methacrylate}\acused{PMMA}
        
        \acro{SiO}
        {Silicon Oxide}\acused{SiO}
        
        \acro{OLR}
        {Organolithium}\acused{OLR}
        
        \acro{IPA}
        {Isopropanol}\acused{IPA}
        
        \acro{DCB}
        {1{,}2-Dichlorobenzene}\acused{DCB}
        
        \acro{PVD}
        {Physical vapor deposition}\acused{PVD}
        
        \acro{RF}
        {Radio frequency}\acused{RF}
        
        \acro{HCl}
        {Hydrochloric acid}\acused{HCl}
        
        \acro{RTE}
        {Resistive thermal evaporation}\acused{RTE}
        
        \acro{AFM}
        {Atomic force microscope}\acused{AFM}
        
        \acro{EQE}
        {External quantum efficiency}\acused{EQE}
        
        \acro{IQE}
        {Internal quantum efficiency}\acused{IQE}
        
    \end{acronym}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: please provide your code in a form that we can run it to see the error, and show exactly what error you got.

Comment: do you really have `\acro{$\lambda}` with only one `$` ?  It is hard to help if you do not provide a test file

Comment: Typing mistake for the $\lambda$

The error is " Missing\endcsname inserted... hyperlink" {{Wavelength}\acused{$\lambda$}}

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The documentation says that for greek letters one should use the following order:

\acro{lambda}[$\lambda$]{Wavelength}